# Map individual lines across two y axes in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to show cause and effect by displaying lines that are connected by two separate y axes.

```
eps_surprise = [56.15, 80.41, 218.48, 5.67, 2.99, 5.67]
stock_movement = [-5.72, 14.52, 18.78, -6.77, 6.03, -6.77]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y = list(zip(eps_surprise,stock_movement))
for i in y:
    ax.plot((0,1),i)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see in the above chart, I want to include a second y axis that would have a range limited to the `min` and `max` of `stock_movement`. However, my attempts in doing so do not result in the desired chart, as what is plotted is then based on the second axis alone, and not the first.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eps_surprise = [56.15, 80.41, 218.48, 5.67, 2.99, 5.67]
stock_movement = [-5.72, 14.52, 18.78, -6.77, 6.03, -6.77]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.set_ylim(min(eps_surprise),max(eps_surprise))
ax2.set_ylim(min(stock_movement),max(stock_movement))

y = list(zip(eps_surprise,stock_movement))
for i in y:
    plt.plot((0,1),i)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The desired output would look something like as follows:
[image]

Comment: you are plotting `eps_surprise` elements with `stock_movement`, so all the `stock_movement` values are at `1` on the x-axis and all the `eps_surprise` values are at `0`. Is this what you are trying to do? You're also plotting all your lines on `ax2` but have limited the extent of the axes which is why you don't see all of your lines. I'm having a hard time understanding what you want your graph to look like. Do you want to be plotting time series of both on the same chart?

Comment: @ramzeek I've edited my post to include an image that shows the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking exactly, but given your question it's the best I can picture.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eps_surprise = [56.15, 80.41, 218.48, 5.67, 2.99, 5.67]
stock_movement = [-5.72, 14.52, 18.78, -6.77, 6.03, -6.77]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.set_ylim(min(eps_surprise),max(eps_surprise))
ax2.set_ylim(min(stock_movement),max(stock_movement))

# plot eps surprise and stock movement on the two separate axes
l1 = ax1.plot(eps_surprise, 'k--', label = 'eps surprise')
l2 = ax2.plot(stock_movement, 'r', label = 'stock movement')

# create legend for both axes
lns = [l1[0], l2[0]]
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax2.legend(lns, labs)

ax1.set_ylabel('eps surprise')
ax2.set_ylabel('stock movement')
```

[image: plot]

Honestly, though, if I were trying to show a relationship between two variables, I'd be more tempted to make a scatter plot or a regression.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit([[i,] for i in eps_surprise],
              [[i,] for i in stock_movement])
x = [[min(eps_surprise)], [max(eps_surprise)]]

plt.plot(eps_surprise, stock_movement, '.')
plt.plot(x, regressor.predict(x))
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('eps surprise')
plt.ylabel('stock movement')
```

[image: other plot]

**UPDATE**

Based on the update in your question of how you want your original figure to look, here's how I would do it. The second set of axes are purely for labelling and instead I scaled the stock movement values to fit on your `ax1` scale.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def map_to_eps(stock_movement, eps_surprise):
    ybounds = [min(stock_movement), max(stock_movement)]
    dy = ybounds[1] - ybounds[0]
    xbounds = [min(eps_surprise), max(eps_surprise)]
    dx = xbounds[1] - xbounds[0]
    return([(y - ybounds[0]) / dy * dx + xbounds[0] for y in stock_movement], dy, dx)

eps_surprise = [56.15, 80.41, 218.48, 5.67, 2.99, 5.67]
stock_movement = [-5.72, 14.52, 18.78, -6.77, 6.03, -6.77]
(stock_eps, dstock, deps) = map_to_eps(stock_movement, eps_surprise)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.set_ylim(min(eps_surprise) - 0.05 * deps,max(eps_surprise) + 0.05 * deps)
ax2.set_ylim(min(stock_movement) - 0.05 * dstock ,max(stock_movement) + 0.05 * dstock)

y = list(zip(eps_surprise,stock_eps))
for i in y:
    ax1.plot((0,1),i)
plt.xticks([])
ax1.set_ylabel('eps surprise')
ax2.set_ylabel('stock movement')
```

[image: edited plot]

Comment: You know, I thought about a scatter plot and thought otherwise, but you're starting to convince me that this is the right approach. It would be nice if there was a solution to the question, but the last demo is making me reconsider my options.

Comment: Now that I understand the question @user1185790, I've provided an update that hopefully answers your question. Note that I scaled the axes limits slightly so that you can see the top and bottom lines clearly.